# Image is not storing in internal memory

Tags: android

I am using this code to store image in internal storage but image is not saving in internal storage, instead it is storing in external storage with path : /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/CAMERA/IMG_2345.,jpg

```
private String saveToInternalMemory(Bitmap bitmap,String imgName){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

    File file = new File(getCacheDir(),"imageDirectory");

    //File directory = cw.getDir("imageDirectory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //File userDirectory = new File(directory,imgName);

    File myPath = new File(file,imgName);

    Log.e("path",myPath.getAbsolutePath());




    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,fos);
        Log.e("img_name",bitmap.toString());


    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
    catch (IOException e){}finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        }catch (IOException e){}
    }
    return myPath.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Can someone please explain me what is the error?

Comment: "but image is not saving in internal storage" -- please explain, **in detail**, how you have determined this. "instead it is storing in external storage with path" -- that is a different file. For example, it is a JPEG, and your code is creating a PNG. Also, **never** catch exceptions without logging them, particularly when you are having problems with the code that is throwing those exceptions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to save my image in phone memory instead of sd card, but it is storing in sdcard. This is the problelm.. and also the " imageDirectory" folder is not created...

Comment: That does not explain, **in detail**, how you have determined that "image is not saving in internal storage". After all, you cannot see [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) very easily on devices. So, my guess is that you are looking in the wrong place. But, until you explain, **in detail**, how you have determined that "image is not saving in internal storage", nobody can help you.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok can you please suggest me where this "imageDirectory"  folder is creating.Can i found this directory in my phone

Comment: Please read [the blog post that I linked to in my previous comment, that I am linking to here as well](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your help sir...

Comment: Is phone storage and internal memory storage are same?

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually when i am removing my sdcard then the image is storing in phone storage but if i reconnect my sdcard then by default it is storing in sdcard

Comment: @CommonsWare Our android's File storage shows two directories sdcard and phone storage, so image is storing in sdcard not in phone storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147015/discussion-between-harshita-and-commonsware).